# Live Stream Audio from a microphone to Softbank Nao humanoid

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, gstreamer, audio-streaming, nao-robot

We are trying to live stream audio from a microphone directly to Nao's speakers. 
We have tried transferring the recorded audio file using microphone to NAO robot using SFTP using Paramiko library on python and playing it on Nao . This works fine but is not real time at all as per our requirement.

We have looked through Stack Overflow and SoftBankRobotics Community for a solution and don't have a heading.

Please comment for any details .

We have tried some code using sendRemoteBuffer method as shown below .

```
def main(robot_IP, robot_PORT=9559, robot_mode=0):
obj = ALProxy("ALAudioDevice")
from pydub import AudioSegment
songPath = 'a.wav'
song = AudioSegment.from_wav(songPath)
try:
    # here is important to note that the second parameter is contigus memory audio data!
    x = obj.sendRemoteBufferToOutput(int(song.frame_count()), id(song._data))
    print "True" if x else "False"
except Exception as e:
    print "error for buffer: "
obj.onUnload()
```

We are getting error --> "could not create a proxy,as there is no current broker in python's world"

Any help/hint would really be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just open a socket and send it?

Comment: We have thought about doing this .. But we are not sure how to stream the audio at NAO's end ?

Comment: Another thing that is bothering us is we will need to send audio from the microphone (outside NAO) send it as "chunks" over a socket(as you mentioned) and then play it on NAO as and when we receive the "chunk" and in a continuous manner to avoid delay . We are not sure how we can achieve this on NAO?

Comment: A socket and send it to nao, then send to the speakers using sendRemoteBufferToOutput (if called from python) or sendLocalBufferToOutput (if called from a c++ cross compiled module). cf http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/naoqi/audio/alaudiodevice-api.html#ALAudioDeviceProxy::sendRemoteBufferToOutput__iCR.AL::ALValueCR (the RemoteBufferXxx method can even potentially be used from a remote computer, and so avoiding the socket (to be tested))

Comment: @AlexandreMazel we have tried using sendRemoteBufferToOutput from the nao's python API, We didn't get a proper example and so we couldn't get it to work. If you have a sample snippet that we can try out, it would really be helpful.

Comment: @szatmary I forgot to tag you. Please see the two comments immediately succeeding your comments.

Comment: @AlexandreMazel  please check the question , we have added some code that we have tried.

Comment: About the error, try doing: obj = ALProxy("ALAudioDevice", robot_IP, robot_PORT)